# Node.js | check days left on account

Tags: node.js

I want to verify Date is valid for subscription.

Date is in UTC format.

when user creates an account i set the expiration date to be the date in 30 days.

Before each action, i want to verify the expiration date of his account.

To get the days left for user i do

```
let oneDay = 24*60*60*1000;
let daysLeft = (userSubscription.expired - new Date())/(oneDay))
```

Now i want to check that if `daysLeft` is 0, then do some action alerting the user.

My problem is, that is if expiration was a year ago, then days left will not be below 0 as i expected, it will be 300+.

how can i enforce it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this you just get the difference between those dates:

```
 let oneDay = 24*60*60*1000;
 let daysLeft = (userSubscription.expired - new Date())/(oneDay))
```

So the result after one year would be 365 - 30 = 335

But you need to check if userSubscription.expired is higher than new Date()

Use something from here: [Compare two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)